# Initializing an observable by an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, observable

How to create an observable that is initialized by an object?

```
function Company(object) {
    this.Code = object != undefined && object.Code != undefined ? ko.observable(object.Code) : ko.observable();
    this.Name = object != undefined && object.Name != undefined ? ko.observable(object.Name).extend({ required: { message: "Nom de la companie est obligatoire" } }) : ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "Nom de la companie est obligatoire" } });  
};
```

//View Model

```
  var company = new AddedCompany();
  self.company = ko.observable(company);
```

I am not getting any exceptions in the console, but the binding does not work properly.
Is initializing an observable with an object possible in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, but you need to use the with binding to change the context to the sub viewmodel (Company in this case)

```
<!-- ko with: company -->
<div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The with binding can be used with and without virtual element